# Focusing On Empty Required Fields

Tags: php, jquery, html, field, onfocus

Haloo, i have a problem here

Its my Validation Script

```
foreach ($product_options as $product_option) {
    if ($product_option['required'] && empty($option[$product_option['product_option_id']])) {

        $json['error']['product']['option'][$product_option['product_option_id']] 
            = sprintf($this->language->get('error_required'), $product_option['name']);
    }
}
```

And its my Div Id

```
<div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
```

For now, that script just show up " fieldname is Required!" 
i want it focus on the empty required field and show the "fieldname is Required!" text , Thank you

Comment: It would be easier to do this in client-side validation. If you want to do it in the server, you have to send back Javascript that sets the focus.

Comment: can you give me an example please ?

Comment: I suggest you use a library like `jquery-validate.js`.

Comment: i can't change the validation because it from opencart

Comment: Where is the input field that you want to focus in? Your question just has a DIV.

Comment: The input field is inside the div

Answer (score 0):

When you detect an error, output Javascript that sets focus on the invalid field.

```
foreach ($product_options as $product_option) {
    if ($product_option['required'] && empty($option[$product_option['product_option_id']])) {

        $json['error']['product']['option'][$product_option['product_option_id']] 
            = sprintf($this->language->get('error_required'), $product_option['name']);
        ?>
        <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#option-<?php echo $product_option['product_option_id'] ?> input").focus();
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't tell where this code is in your script. I'm assuming it's in the code that generates the output page, and you've already started printing HTML and it's after you loaded jQuery, so you can insert a `<script>` block like that. You probably need to tweek it to fit your exact needs, so just consider this to show the basic idea.